# Time Machine: chain of snapshots broke, how to restore?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have noticed that Time Machine somehow started to ignore snapshots on a backup disk. Particularly, it says that the oldest backup is 24 December 2021, although I can see snapshots from the end of 2020 on the backup disk.
Please see the attached screenshot.

Is it possible to fix this problem with Time Machine?
This happened on the computer with macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

[image]

**EDIT**. Just found a command-line command to confirm that it sees only the latest snapshot:

```
❯ tmutil listbackups
/Volumes/BUPBL4-Mac/Backups.backupdb/Kabanovs MacBookPro/2021-12-24-004025
```

Comment: Not using this OS, but wonder if you use the "Browse Other Time Machine Disks"* option, do you see the missing ones? (As if somehow a second backup set had been added.)  *in an older OS this browse option is seen when right-clicking the dock icon for TM

Comment: @revans19, no, it just shows the only backup disk

Comment: Was just a thought. Surely someone will come along here with an answer. Meanwhile, if you want to look around there, someone is hosting an archive of the ancient "Pondini" time machine troubleshooting website at http://oldtoad.net/pondini.org/OSX/Home.html (not sure how relevant to a modern OS like 10.15).

Comment: Thank you, @revans19, looks like a ton of information on Time machine!